# Specify PHP version in MAMP

Tags: php, apache, mamp

Using Mamp 3.3, the `conf/apache/httpd.conf` file has the following line to specify PHP:

```
LoadModule php5_module /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/modules/libphp5.so
```

When I update the line to a different version of PHP e.g.

```
LoadModule php5_module /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.29/modules/libphp5.so
```

As soon as I restart MAMP it automatically resets it back to 5.6.10. Is there a way to force a PHP version?

Comment: Are you editing the template file?

Comment: I'm editing the following file `conf/apache/extra/httpd.conf`

Comment: Sounds like you might be editing the wrong file. Is there another httpd.conf file one level higher, at conf/apache?

Comment: Copied the path wrong it's `conf/apache/httpd.conf`

Comment: Have you tried to use the preferences where you start MAMP to set this?

Comment: The preferences just offer 5.5 or 5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for this in MAMP forums. Just rename PHP versions not required. For example after renaming the following, they are not shown in the preferences:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/X_php5.6.10
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/X_php5.4.42
```